# Operator font in beamer/metropolis

Tags: beamer, fontspec, beamer-metropolis

When using the metropolis theme for beamer, I get text and math in Fira Sans, *except* for math operators. I compile the following MWE using LuaTeX.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    Ordinary text.
    \[ a^2 + b^2 = \sin^2(x) - \mathsf{y} + \mathrm{z}  \]
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The outcome for me is that a, b, 2 and x are set in Fira Sans Light Italic, and y is set in Fira Sans Light, but sin is set in the sans font of (I guess) Latin Modern. (The z is also in Latin Modern, but this is expected behaviour from beamer.)

Unsurprisingly, I get the same result if I replace `\usetheme{metropolis}` with

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setsansfont[ItalicFont={Fira Sans Light Italic},
  BoldFont={Fira Sans},
  BoldItalicFont={Fira Sans Italic}]%
  {Fira Sans Light}
```

I guess that this is to do with beamer's patching parts of the math fonts to match the text font (see [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406705/60439)). However, I don't understand the font system well enough to modify this.

There was [a similar question asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43135/60439), but I've no idea how to apply that answer when using `fontspec`, or if this is even possible.

Is there a way to change the operator font to match the upright/sans math font (i.e., Fira Sans Light)?

Comment: I have found that loading `\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}` automatically sets the operators in the (upright) text font, and looks otherwise almost identical to beamer's output, the exception being that `\mathrm` is now the upright text font instead of the inherited Latin Modern. Still, I would be interested to know how to change the operator font by hand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe changing the operator font could be a workaround:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\DeclareSymbolFont{sfoperators}{OT1}{FiraSans-LF}{l}{n}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\operator@font}{\mathgroup\symsfoperators}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    Ordinary text.
    \[ a^2 + b^2 = \sin^2(x) - \mathsf{y} + \mathrm{z}  \]
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use the `moloch` theme, a more modern fork of the `metropolis` theme. `moloch` does not change the fonts, so you will get a consistent set by default (computer modern sans):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    Ordinary text.
    \[ a^2 + b^2 = \sin^2(x) - \mathsf{y} + \mathrm{z}  \]
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Would you mind explaining a bit about what's going on with `\DeclareSymbolFont` here? In particular, how do you know that `FiraSans-LF` is the right thing to enter for the font family? I can't figure this out from `fntguide.pdf` (which must presumably be out of date, because it says "Font  family  names  should  contain  up  to  five  lower  case  letters").

Comment: @AlexWatson I'm actually not a font expert, so other people might be able to explain this better or even judge if this really a solution or just some dirty hack. About the font name: I actually searched in the tex installation for some fira font files and found some in `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fira` from where I got the name to use in `\DeclareSymbolFont`.