# Font issue in math mode in Beamer metropolis theme

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fontspec, beamer-metropolis

I'm learning to use the beautiful Metropolis theme, but I have a long-standing problem with the fonts in math mode. As you can see from the image, the font of the elementary functions is poorly displayed. I'm compiling with XeLaTex.

[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
        \usetheme[progressbar=foot,numbering=none]{metropolis}
        \usepackage[italian]{babel}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{centernot}
        \usepackage{enumerate}
        \usepackage{array}
        \usepackage{fontspec}
        \usepackage{semantic}
    
  \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item $a_n = |n|$ (valore assoluto)
            \item $a_n = n^2$ (potenza ad esponente pari)
            \item $a_n = n^3$ (potenza ad esponente dispari)
            \item $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ (reciproco di potenza pari)
            \item $a_n = \frac{1}{n^3}$ (reciproco di potenza pari)
            \item $a_n = \sqrt[2]{n}$ (radice di indice pari)
            \item $a_n = \sqrt[3]{n}$ (radice di indice dispari)
            \item $a_n = \log_2 n$ (logaritmo con base maggiore di 1)
            \item $a_n = \log_{\frac{1}{3}} n$ (logaritmo con base tra 0 e 1)
            \item $a_n = 2^n$ (esponenziale ad esponente maggiore di 1)
            \item $a_n = \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^n$ (esponenziale ad esponente tra 0 e 1)
            \item $a_n = \sin n $ (seno)
            \item $a_n = \cos n $ (coseno)  
            \item $a_n = \tan n $ (tangente)
            \item $a_n = \arcsin n $ (arcoseno)
\end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: As always on this size, you get nowhere unless you post a full minimal example others can copy and test as is. Otherwise people will just pass on your question

Comment: Now it should be ok. Sorry.

Comment: Are you sure this is everything because I don't see a font that thin when I use the MWE (BTW you might want to remove `[<+->]` as it s not relevant here.

Comment: Ahh, my bad it's using fira sans which I do not have installed (seemingly).

Comment: Of course I have installed Fire font in Windows and compiled with XeLaTex. It it everything here.

Comment: The interesting part is that I get these errors under TexLive 2020: `kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `Fira Sans Light Italic', contains ' '` and the theme has implemented its own tests to look for the fonts, a test that might now be working any more.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478920/3929

Comment: Thank you so much. Following the related question it seems to work.  I just can't understand if the square root is made with the correct Fira font.