# Beamer - unicode-math, wrong font for operators

Tags: beamer, math-mode

When I use the `\Pr` in math mode, it displays a different font rather than computer modern as below:
[image]

My MWE (in XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=32, hyperref=unicode, dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\let\mathbbalt\mathbb
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\let\mathbb\mathbbalt
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Iwona}

\title{A title}
\author{Some authors}
\date{A date}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
$p(s',r\mid s,a) = \Pr\{S_{t+1} = s', R_{t+1} = r \mid S_t = s, A_t = a\}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to force `\Pr` to use Computer Modern font there?

---

Thank you for all of your suggestions and answers.
I found some more points that I think should be shared for other people that face this problem:

- I use Overleaf with TeXLive 2022 so the command `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` got the option clash:

```
The package fontspec has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [no-math]
Adding the global options:
  ,no-math
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

put the no-math option to the preamble will fix this error:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=32, hyperref=unicode, dvipsnames, no-math]{beamer}
```

- One can use another solution: by adding the option `mathrm=sym` to unicode-math package, the problem goes away.

```
\usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}
```

Edit 1: update the title for clarification.
Edit 2: adding anther solution.

Comment: BTW you can remove all lines from `\usepackage{datetime}` to `\setdefaultlanguage{english}` and get the same output. I'd also suggest changing the title of the question to something similar to `Beamer - serif font theme, wrong font for operators` or similar. It more precisely describes the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476516/operator-font-in-beamer-metropolis/478920#478920

Comment: What is the command \Pr?

Comment: `\Pr` is used to denote a probability

Comment: @daleif: thank you, these are the packages that I load in a full document so I think I should include them in the question. I will rename the title for more clarification.

Comment: It is called `minimal example` for a reason. Here the issue can be replicated with a smaller example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to use the default computer modern font, I suggest to load `fontspec` with the `no-math` option so it lets the fonts used for math alone (and also not to load unicode-math, as you don't want to change the font used for math)

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[aspectratio=32, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

%\usepackage{datetime}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\let\mathbbalt\mathbb
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\let\mathbb\mathbbalt
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Iwona}


\title{A title}
\author{Some authors}
\date{A date}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
$p(s',r\mid s,a) = \Pr\{S_{t+1} = s', R_{t+1} = r \mid S_t = s, A_t = a\}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your suggestions and answers.
I found some more points that I think should be shared for other people that face this problem:

- I use Overleaf with TeXLive 2022 so the command `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` got the option clash:

```
The package fontspec has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [no-math]
Adding the global options:
  ,no-math
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
```

put the no-math option to the preamble will fix this error:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=32, hyperref=unicode, dvipsnames, no-math]{beamer}
```

- One can use another solution: by adding the option `mathrm=sym` to unicode-math package, the problem goes away.

```
\usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}
```

Comment: --- " got the option clash": load fontspec before unicode-math (or remove the later). Nothing to do with overleaf or tl22

Comment: `hyperref=unicode` should hardly be necessary and instead of `dvipsnames` it would be better to write `xcolor=dvipsnames`