# Beamer fonts in inkscape textext?

Tags: beamer, fonts, inkscape

I use Inkscape to make graphics for my beamer presentations, and I use the [textext](https://inkscape.org/~jcwinkler/%E2%98%85textext) extension to add math to my images.

However, the font in textext doesn't match the standard beamer font. I can use \sffamily for text and \mathsf for math (unless I need italic latin characters as variable names). But I can't find a unifying approach that also works with greek letters.

I can add commands to the TexText preamble file. I've tried adding the cmbright package, but then the greek letters come out as gibberish.

What's the best thing to do here?

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452657/36296  or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406705/36296 can help (just a guess, I don't have this textext extension to test)